# Form not saving if try to upload image with Paperclip

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, paperclip

so paperclip, seems as if there is a different way to get it working every time i use it.

So at the moment i try and submit a form but it fails and re renders the form (which is what its supposed to do if the form does not save).

This is my setup so far

Gemfile

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
```

Controller

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end

def create
 @user = current_user
 @post = @user.posts.new(params[:post])
  if @post.save
   redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Post Successfully Created'
  else
   render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Post Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user

 attr_accessible :comments, :title, :category_id, :user_id, :photo
 has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
end
```

Form

```
<%= form_for @post, :class => 'post-form',  :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

<%= f.label :title, "Title", :class => 'title_label' %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>

<%= f.label :category_id, "Choose Category", :class => 'title_label' %>
<%= f.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, :prompt => "Please Select a Category") %>

<%= f.label :comments, "Comments", :class => 'title_label'  %>
<%= f.text_area :comments %><br>

<%= f.file_field :photo %>

<%= f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'btn' %>

<% end %>
```

My migration to add photo was successful as my schema looks like so

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "comments"
t.integer  "category_id"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
t.string   "photo_file_name"
t.string   "photo_content_type"
t.integer  "photo_file_size"
t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
```

end

Can anyone see reason why this is not working as expected?

EDIT

Do i need ImageMagick installed to allow the upload of an image or is this just for rendering an image in the view?

ok so from the comments i have started to try and debug and put this in my view

```
<%= @post.errors.full_messages %>
```

I get this returned

```
["Photo C:/Users/RICHAR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/bitman20130724-5600-agvtgn.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.", "Photo C:/Users/RICHAR~1/AppData/Local/Temp/bitman20130724-5600-agvtgn.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command."]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use Rails 3.x version? Try to print form errors: debug @post.errors

Comment: does this go in my controller? in create action?

Comment: you can probably use this in view, `<%= @post.errors %>` to view it in browser.

Comment: i just get this back #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x44f20c8>

Comment: you don't have to `:html => { :multipart => true }` when using a `file_field`. this is done by default in rails: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/file_field

Comment: thanks for the tip, would this prevent the form submitting and saving though?

Comment: I have used `remote: true` in a form when creating comments, and also I had the upload files field, when I was uploading the `remote: true` is ignored. So the problem is not in `remote: true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**
From paperclip documentation:

**ImageMagick** must be installed and **Paperclip** must have **access** to it. To ensure that it does, on your command line, run which convert (one of the ImageMagick utilities). This will give you the path where that utility is installed. For example, it might return `/usr/local/bin/convert`.

Then, in your environment config file, let Paperclip know to look there by adding that directory to its path.

In `development` mode, you might add this line to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/"
```

---

**Step 2** 
 For `agvtgn.png is not recognized by the 'identify' command.` error:

Not sure how you do this in windows, for linux this is what you need to do:

```
$ which identify
/path/to/identify
```

Set `command_path` to that path in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/path/to"
```

also you need `ImageMagick` to be installed

http://ganeshprasadsr.blogspot.com/2010/12/paperclip-issue-is-not-recognized-by.html

---

**What I think** - You just need to install ImageMagick.

---

p.s. Windows is the worst development machine. You could install at least a virtual machine running on linux.

Comment: agreed windows is the worst dev machine....EVER..however its all i have access to in the days (use linux at home), VM not possible, trust me if it was i would be using it.... Ive added Paperclip.options and now seems to be working, though im sure the path isnt /usr/local/bin, but nevertheless its all working so far

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` this path si just a sample of how it might be. Good luck in your development ;).